# Jquery / JS - Update Drop Down

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got this set up on JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/melissal/FmEcw/

Now when I change the selection of the 'Quantity' dropdown, it changes the price of the paper (above). I want this to show in the 2nd drop down. So when you select the 'Paper' dropdown you see two options, 'Regular' and 'Premium (+ $XXX)', but I can't figure out how to get the new price to show up. Is that possible?

Here's the HTML:

```
Paper: $<span id="paper_div"></span><br />

<div id="product-options">
<form action="/cart/add" id="ProjectProductForm" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <div style="display:none;">
        <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="POST"/>
    </div>          
    <div id="product-options-qty">
        <span class="text">Quantity: </span>
        <span class="form">
            <div class="input select">
                <select name="field_6" class="text_select" id="field_6">
                    <option value="225">15 @ $225.00</option>
                    <option value="240">20 @ $240.00</option>
                    <option value="250">30 @ $250.00</option>
                    <option value="270">40 @ $270.00</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div id="product-options-paper">
        <span class="text">Paper: </span>
        <span class="form">
            <div class="input select">
                <select name="field_6" class="text_select">
                    <option value="1">Regular</option>
                    <option value="2">Premium (+ $<span id="paper_div"></span>)</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </span>
    </div>

</form>
```

And the JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#field_6").change(function() {
    var id = $(this).val();
    $('#price_div').html($(this).val());

    var premium_paper = id * .25;
    var premium_paper = parseFloat(Math.round(premium_paper * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
    $('#paper_div').html(premium_paper);        
}).change();    
});
```

Comment: So if I pick 30 as the quantity, Premium in the second drop down should read "Premium (+ $62.50)? Side note, IDs **must** be unique.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right. (And I think I've removed the only duplicate ID? Didn't see it before. Thanks :))

Comment: So like this http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/rv3Nd/? Note that I added an ID to the second drop down to making selecting it easier. Also, both your drop downs have the same name attribute which you probably don't want.

Comment: That's it!... except the first selection doesn't have the price set anymore. When I leave the ".change()" at the end, it does though. Is there any reason why I would take that out? It works perfectly with it in. Thanks so much!

Comment: Oh no, sorry I left out that out for testing. Will update and post as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `$('#field_7 option:eq(1)').html('Premium (+ $'+premium_paper+')')`:

Note that I added an ID to the second select. You may also want to give your drop downs different name attributes.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#field_6").change(function () {
        var id = $(this).val();
        $('#price_div').html($(this).val());
        var premium_paper = id * .25;
        var premium_paper = parseFloat(Math.round(premium_paper * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
        $('#paper_div').html(premium_paper);
        $('#field_7 option:eq(1)').html('Premium (+ $'+premium_paper+')')
    }).change();
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/rv3Nd/1/)**